# Setting ipSecurityRestrictions to Deny is not changing Access restriction to On

Tags: azure

When I apply the following code in the "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" section of an ARM for an Azure Function, it does not change the Access restriction to On in the Portal.

```
"ipSecurityRestrictions": [
    {
        "ipAddress": "Any",
        "action": "Deny",
        "priority": 2147483647,
        "name": "Deny all",
        "description": "Deny all access"
    }
],
"ipSecurityRestrictionsDefaultAction": "Deny",
```

[image]

However...if I click on the Access restriction I can see that the Deny restriction is added:

[image]

If I do this from the Portal and export the template it gives me the same ARM as above, and the Access restriction is changed to On, so something strange is going on here :-)

[image]

Comment: The image you provided seems like an app service. Could you confirm on it whether it is an app service web app or a function app. @Tommy Selggren

Comment: It's a Function App

Comment: Ok will work on it and update. @Tommy Selggren

Comment: I will try on an App Service as well, and if it's set on an app service then Microsoft has some issue, and I will create a case to them...

Comment: Can you check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547554/19785512) works in your case. @Tommy Selggren

Comment: Actually not the same as you are setting the action to Allow. In my case I'm setting Deny... Could be that if you set allow for a VNET, that it's switching the Access restriction to On. For Deny all it does not...

Comment: Have you tried the provided code with deny action? @Tommy Selggren

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547554/19785512) thread which is very similar to what you require.

Use below `Microsoft.Web/sites/config` resource as shown.

```bash
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[concat(variables('functionAppName'), '/web')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "numberOfWorkers": 1,
        "defaultDocuments": [
          "index.html",
          "iisstart.htm"
        ],
        "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
        "phpVersion": "5.6",
        "requestTracingEnabled": false,
        "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
        "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2019",
        "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
        "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
        "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
        "publishingUsername": "[concat('$', variables('functionAppName'))]",
        "scmType": "VSTSRM",
        "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
        "webSocketsEnabled": false,
        "alwaysOn": false,
        "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
        "virtualApplications": [
          {
            "virtualPath": "/",
            "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
            "preloadEnabled": true
          }
        ],
        "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
        "experiments": {
          "rampUpRules": [
          ]
        },
        "autoHealEnabled": false,
        "cors": {
          "allowedOrigins": [],
          "supportCredentials": false
        },
        "localMySqlEnabled": false,
        "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
          {
                        "vnetSubnetResourceId": "<VNETResourceID>",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "tag": "Default",
                        "priority": 34,
                        "name": "[concat('{0}-myVnet', parameters('vnetw'))]"
                    }
        ],
        "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [],
        "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
        "http20Enabled": false,
        "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
        "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
        "reservedInstanceCount": 1
      }
    }
```